# How can I make switching between Boostrap tabs dependent on a confirmation dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried two things that I thought would work, and naturally, neither of them do. Here are the two ways I'm currently trying, with some JSFiddle sample code (I'm using JQuery 2.2.1).

The HTML sample:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#about" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="tab">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="about">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="txtAbout">About me: </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAbout">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="contact">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="txtContact">Contact me: </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtContact">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My current attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/0noo2bwg/3/

```
var isDirty = false;

$(".form-control").change(function () {
  isDirty = true;
});

$('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!isDirty) {
    $(this).tab('show');
  }
});
```

As is (thankfully?) evident in the fiddle, `e.preventDefault()` doesn't stop the link even when `isDirty` is `true`. I stripped the dialog code out of here since it wasn't affecting the result.

Here's the other attempt (with the dialog HTML and JS logic included): https://jsfiddle.net/kLe75gtr/3/

```
var isDirty = false;

$(".form-control").change(function () {
  isDirty = true;
});

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
  if (isDirty) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
      resizable: false,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Leave": function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          isDirty = false;
          $(e.target.text).tab("show");
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

`e.preventDefault()` has to happen first or the tab will switch while the dialog is being addressed. Here, `$(e.target.text).tab("show")` just doesn't switch the tab. Possibly because it's being prevented in the same function...idk.

Anyone have an idea to make one of these work? Or a different route? Web dev isn't my strong suit so maybe I'm missing something simple. Apologies if I've left out any other crucial info, started drinking in hopes that would help my thinking capacity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the leave function of dialog with the following line.

```
$(e.target).click();
```

I have updated the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kLe75gtr/5/

Comment: Genius. Thank you, friend.